# Cannot change working directory in Ubuntu using cd

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cd-command

I'm fairly new to working in Linux so bear with me.
I want to run some 16S sequencing data through QIIME2, so I installed Ubuntu on my computer (Windows 11) along with the WSL. I managed to get everything up and running, but was unable to change my directory. Even after exiting QIIME and trying to cd in Ubuntu, the only two commands I could get to work are: `cd /mnt/c/Users/username` and `cd ~`.

Listing the contents in my directory (ls) after navigating to either of these lists my computer's file folders, including Desktop, Documents, etc., but I cannot cd to any of them. I also have Miniconda installed, if this makes a difference; it is required to run QIIME. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hello and welcome - it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to include some of the commands that you tried that **didn't** work, along with the exact error messages.

Comment: Don't forget that space is a *delimiter* for commands, so if your directories/files contain spaces in the names, you need to *escape* or *quote* them to access them, as a space will be treated as *delimiter* and it'll action what follows the space as the next *operand*...  Case also matters (ie. `d` and `D` are different characters)